# How to disable/unbind Alt+Enter in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have tried unbinding the key via eclipse IDE (General->Preferences->Keys) but with no effect. My eclipse applications is throwing the following message whenever the keys are entered for editing cells in my grid tables.

'No property page found for .'

The key ALT+Enter seem to be attached to Property page. How to unbind the same in my eclipse application?

Comment: Did you try restarting eclipse?

Comment: Actually, the keys page is the right location to look for. Have you tried putting alt+enter into the search field? This should show you any commands bount to this key and you can unbind them - there is a designated button for...

Comment: Is this your own RCP that you are asking about? The Eclipse IDE preferences don't affect your RCP.